# AngularJS: ngModel - convert special symbols

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, angularjs-directive

In case of security I'm sending all special characters from my server encoded (e.g. stored in my DB symbol `<` outputs as `&lt;`). 
I have an input in my form

`<input ng-model="form.description">`

But the value, inserted to the input is shown as is `&lt;`. What should I do, to change ng-model to actual `<`? 
I already found a lot of information about [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) but can't create a working approach.

Currently I'm thinking about directive

```
function TrustAsHTMLDirective($sce) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, elem) {
                scope.$watch('ngModel', function (after, before) {
                    if (after && after !== before) {
                        scope.ngModel =  $sce.trustAsHtml(elem[0].value);
                    }
                })
            }
        };
```

That should be used like this `<input ng-model="form.description" trust-as-html>`, but it does not work, moreover probably I would need this for all inputs in my app.

So the question is - how to change ng-model to actual value, but keep my app secure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash usescape function to convert HTML entities &, <, >, ", and ' in string to their corresponding characters.

**Syntax**

```
_.unescape([string=''])
```

**Example:**

_.unescape('fred, barney, & pebbles');

output => 'fred, barney, & pebbles'

Comment: I can't use the function because of security reasons.